# Multiple Select, Count and Where Statements in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, count, group-by

I am trying to generate a report for use with a chart, i have tried many different statements but just cant get this to work.

Basically, i want to be able to display the records of calls in my database, grouped by date, and counted to give an accurate picture.

i.e.

```
| Date     | Answered Calls | Missed Calls | Total Calls |
| 1-1-2016 | 10             | 2            | 12
| 2-1-2016 | 15             | 1            | 16
```

Etc etc

However, using the below statement (This does not include the Total Calls Count), i keep getting the following -

```
SELECT  (SELECT DATE(`created`)
         FROM   mp_wp_call_report_pstn
        ) AS created_date,

        (SELECT `Extension`
         FROM   mp_wp_call_report_pstn
        ) AS Extension,

        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM   mp_wp_call_report_pstn
         WHERE `Call type` = "Incoming" 
               AND `Extension` != 2504 
               AND `created` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        ) AS CallsAnswered,

        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM   mp_wp_call_report_pstn
         WHERE `Call type` = "Incoming" 
         AND `Extension` = 2504 
         AND `created` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        ) AS CallsRecieved

GROUP BY DATE(`created_date`) 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

> MySQL said: Documentation - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY
>       DATE(`created_date`) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 22

To get the missed calls, we just take away answered from received.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is your FROM clause?

Comment: In this cases, you should try reduce your query to a minumum to make it work. Then you start adding fields until you find the error. But here you need a FROM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all this subqueries, simply count different calls and group by date and extension.

```
SELECT DATE(`created`) AS created_date, 
       `Extension`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `Call type` = "Incoming" 
                     AND `Extension` != 2504 
                     AND `created` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CallsAnswered,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `Call type` = "Incoming" 
                     AND `Extension` = 2504 
                     AND `created` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CallsRecieved
FROM mp_wp_call_report_pstn
GROUP BY DATE(`created`), `Extension`
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in a single table. You shouldn't be using sub-queries.

Push the date and call_type criteria into the where clause, and group by the date of the phone call.

Something like this should put you on the right track:

```
select DATE(`created`) as created_date,
  sum((case when (`Extension` != 2504) then 1 else 0 end)) AS CallsAnswered,
  sum((case when (`Extension` = 2504) then 1 else 0 end)) AS CallsReceived,
  count(*) as total_calls
from mp_wp_call_report_pstn
where `created` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  and `Call type` = "Incoming"
group by created_date
```